# how to drive a VCSEL?

Tags: driver, laser, laser-driver

I want to drive a VCSEL with the [MAX3795](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3795.pdf) driver, but this ship has a very complicated circuit on it pins.

Is there is another available driver with a simpler circuit that i can use ?

Answer (score 3):

Driving a VCSEL (or other laser diode) can be done with no IC at all. The circuit can be as simple as a *bias tee*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2MEFy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What the Maxim chip does is reduce cost by eliminating the inductor from the circuit, and gives a way to adjust the bias and modulation currents programmatically (with external digitally adjustable resistors). It also provides feedback features that enable building a standard fiber optic transceiver module (such as an [SFP module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver)), and a shutdown pin that would be helpful for designing a product with eye safety requirements.

Comment: thank you, but i want to send a PRBS with the VCSEL through a tissue, receive it on the other side with a PIN photodiode and calculate the BER. So it wont be possible with this circuit i think.

Comment: Replace V1 with a PRBS sequence generator and it should work fine. You may need to work out a better value for L1 (or just buy an off-the-shelf bias tee from a place like MiniCircuits).

Comment: You can calculate BER with pseudo or a fixed waveform. If the signal to noise ratio is low it doesn't matter what you put through regards data.

Comment: Do you really need L1 if I1 is a half decent constant current generator? After all it's just about modulating the current through the diode (laser or VCSEL)?

Comment: @Andyaka, From the specs of the Maxim chip OP linked, I am assuming he is working in the 1 - 4 Gb/s range. you can get the current source within 1.5 cm of the laser, you could probably get away with no inductor. If you're building a PCB, that's doable, but if you're using a benchtop supply for the current source, probably not.

Comment: @ThePhoton OK undertood... and, he doesn't need the chip if the VCSEL is lowish power and even if it's not he can use the inbuilt photodiode to control laser output safely if it's a test bench thing.

Comment: why the MAX 3795 has a limitation between 1Gbps and 4.25Gbps ? can we use it for lower bit rate ?

Comment: @optical, at very low speeds, the modulation could start to interact with the power control circuit (if you use automatic power control), leading to unpredictable behavior. Other than that I don't see a physical reason for a lower limit in what Maxim published --- but Maxim won't have tested the performance at lower speeds, and isn't promising anything about its suitability for use at lower speeds.

Comment: @ThePhoton ok i see, so it would be better not to use this driver if i want to send a much lower bitrate, like 100 Mbps ?

Comment: It's probably not the best solution. But depending on what you're trying to do it might be a "good enough" solution.